# Laravel Tailwind the abstraction is not taking effect when using the @apply directive

Tags: laravel-mix, tailwind-css

I'm using Laravel 8 Jetstream with Tailwind 2.

I got these navigation item classes:

Active:

```
class = "bg-gray-900 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
```

Normal item:

```
class = "text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
```

So far so good, but when I take those classes to the `@apply` directive

** app.css **

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

.active{
    @apply bg-gray-900 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium;
}

.navitem{
    @apply text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium;
}
```

** Navigation file in blade**

```
{{--MENU desktop--}}
   <div class="hidden sm:block sm:ml-6">
       <div class="flex space-x-4">
        @auth()
          <a href="#" class="navitem">Dashboard</a>
          <a href="#" class="active">Projects</a>
        @endauth
       </div>
   </div>
```

The elements' classes are not taking effect, I can only see the names of the elements in simple black text, without the classes working.

Here is how my webpack file looks like:
** webpack.mix.js **

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
        postCss: [
            require('postcss-import'),
            require('tailwindcss'),
        ]
    })
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));
```

After having executed:

```
$ npm run dev
```

The changes do not take effect.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer to this question instead? Makes it easier for people coming to this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's now working after having changed my *WebPack* file to the following:

`webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);
```

After doing this, I executed it again

```
npm run dev
```

And on my web browser, I removed the cookies and reloaded the page (F5).

Now the changes on the Tailwind 2 `@apply` directive do take effect.